# Selenium - Web Scrapping a Power BI report

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I would like to use selenium to scrape the data from the table on this website: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiM2ZiOGM4ODMtYzU0ZS00NzVlLTkyNjgtY2EwYzg0ZWVmMGI1IiwidCI6IjRlMjRkMDI2LWI5MTYtNGNiMS04YWZmLTI1ZmZhNzA1ZWVhMSIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D

It seems that I cannot inspect the page. Does anyone have any clue how I can access the table and save the data in a pandas dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far? What specific problems faced?

Comment: I cannot access the table so as to use find by ID. The table is not HTML, is Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is an HTML element and that is present on the page can be inspected. Hit the F12 key on Chrome and hover over the table.

[image: This worked for me]

The table is a div with role of "presentation", each row is a div with role of "row".

Comment: My concern is that when I do so, it seems that the table is not accessible, I cannot see an ID or name for that element. Is it HTML?

Comment: @Michaella Yes, it is HTML. Not every element has an ID or name. Some HTML element don't have attributes at all.

Comment: So for example, how would you "guide" chrome to choose the first row and save the data in a pd df?

Comment: @Michaella For this you will have to ask another question.

Comment: @Michaella [Here.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @Carapace First of all thanks a lot! Have you found any identifier for the table so as I can use this code?

Answer (score 0):

collect all element (`//div[@role='gridcell']`), this will collect all the cell data and loop through it ! There are 7 columns so make a DF with 7 columns and add through the loop . Also check the `"aria-colindex"` attribute to check the column index.